# Copy elements of list to new list

Tags: c#, list

I have a structure:

```
public struct rawData {

    public string recType;          
    public string ncmCode;         
    public string depotNo;         
    public string accNo;              
    public string kVK;             
    public string callPut;         
    public string quanSetUnset;   
    public string abbNameOTC;  
}

public List<rawData> myData = new List<rawData>();
rawData tempRawData = new rawData();
```

into which I import data to from csv.

My question is, depeding on `accNo`, how can I copy just specific "rows" into a new list of the same structure.

I can loop through the list

```
if (account == "xxxxx") {
    for (int i = 0; i < myData.Count; i++) {
        if (myData[i].accNo == account) {
            myData.CopyTo(acc85RawD, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Im using the copyto but its wrong as that copies to a array, the index i, i need it to copy all elements of index i to a new list....

any help? thanks

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Which language do you use? What is acc85RawD?

Comment: c#, acc85rawD is the "new list"

Answer (score 3):

The projection in LINQ might help..

```
myData.Where(i=>i.accNo==account).Select(i=>new rawData{recType=i.recType,..});
```

Comment: Thanks bazz; how does this help? im a newb to c#, any sources you recommend I can read...?

Comment: To work with the collections in C#, LINQ is a must. You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx)

Comment: :-) Thanks ill have a look now